# Compute the cycle deompositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Consider the permutations $\sigma=(1,2)(3,4)$ and $\tau=(1,2,3,4)$ of the symmetric group $S_4$.
Compute the cycle decompositions of $\sigma^2,\sigma^{-1},\sigma^{-2},\tau^{-1},\sigma ◦ \tau, \tau◦\sigma, \tau^2, \tau^{-2} $ and $\tau^3$

I already have the answers to these however I don't understand how they got there could someone please help me explain and breakdown the cycle decompositions.

Comment: Which ones don't you understand? Do you clearly understand how to multiply permutations? If not, you should probably go back and read your text or notes again.

Comment: struggling with the $\sigma ◦ \tau$ and $\tau ◦ \sigma$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sigma\circ \tau = (1\ 2)(3\ 4)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$. Then $1\to 2\to 1$, $2\to 3\to 4$, $3\to 4\to 3$, and $4\to 1\to 2$. $\tau\circ\sigma$ is similar. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Hi @rogerl I have been looking at some other questions, hope you could help me with this. I am struggling to understand the cycle permutation, $(1,2,3)(1,2)$ I understand $1\to 2$, then $2\to 3$ so $1\to 3$ not sure what to do then though as there is no 3 on the right, do I move over onto the left? Getting myself really confused.

Comment: To see what this does to $1$, you first apply the right-hand permutation, getting $2$, then the left-hand permutation (to $2$), getting $3$. So $1\to 3$. Similarly, $2\to 1$ from the right-hand permutation, and then $1\to 2$, so that $2\to 2$. Finally, $3$ is left unchanged on the right, and $3\to 1$ on the left. So overall you get $1\to 3$, $2\to 2$, $3\to 1$, or $(1\ 3)$.